# Wifi not working on laptop

Tags: networking, drivers

https://pastebin.com/xk0W4qrz

Ran the script listed here:

[My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Wifi showed up when first booted, but upon attempting connection it disappeared.

Comment: Based on [Wifi Drops and Reconnects with UBUNTU 14.04 (Realtek RTL8188)](/a/500421/175814) could you please run `sudo modprobe -r rtl8188ee && sudo modprobe rtl8188ee swenc=1 ips=0` and try to connect again? Thanks.